# JavaScript Array of Arrays: want to get the first row where the value is 'PROCESSED'

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, find

How do I return only the first value that passes the condition where the value is '`PROCESSED`' from the following array?

```
[
  [ '21/01/2021 11:11:57', '111', 'IN PROGRESS' ],
  [ '21/01/2021 11:09:07', '222', 'PROCESSED' ],
  [ '21/01/2021 11:08:57', '333', 'PROCESSED' ],
  [ '21/01/2021 11:08:57', '444', 'PROCESSED' ],
  [ '21/01/2021 11:07:25', '555', 'PROCESSED' ],
]
```

I want to return the whole row and the index in the original array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to return the whole row and the index in the original array.

As you want the index, you can use [.findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) with a combination of [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to extract the string at the second index (`[,,status]`) from your array. You can then return true for the first item where the second index is `'PROCESSED'` to obtain the index. Once you have the index, you can grab the  row (ie: the inner array at the index):

```js
const arr = [ [ '21/01/2021 11:11:57', '111', 'IN PROGRESS' ], [ '21/01/2021 11:09:07', '222', 'PROCESSED' ], [ '21/01/2021 11:08:57', '333', 'PROCESSED' ], [ '21/01/2021 11:08:57', '444', 'PROCESSED' ], [ '21/01/2021 11:07:25', '555', 'PROCESSED' ], ];

const idx = arr.findIndex(([,,status]) => status === "PROCESSED");
const row = arr[idx];
console.log(idx, row);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const data = [
  ["21/01/2021 11:11:57", "111", "IN PROGRESS"],
  ["21/01/2021 11:09:07", "222", "PROCESSED"],
  ["21/01/2021 11:08:57", "333", "PROCESSED"],
  ["21/01/2021 11:08:57", "444", "PROCESSED"],
  ["21/01/2021 11:07:25", "555", "PROCESSED"],
];

const result = data.filter((item) => item[2] === "PROCESSED")[0];

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use **`Array#findIndex`**

```js
const arr = [[ '21/01/2021 11:11:57', '111', 'IN PROGRESS' ], [ '21/01/2021 11:09:07', '222', 'PROCESSED' ], [ '21/01/2021 11:08:57', '333', 'PROCESSED' ], [ '21/01/2021 11:08:57', '444', 'PROCESSED' ], [ '21/01/2021 11:07:25', '555', 'PROCESSED' ], ];

let ind = arr.findIndex(a=> a[2] == 'PROCESSED');

console.log(arr[ind],ind)
```